# enviar mail con test mail server tool

Tags: php, email

Necesito habilitar el envío de mails por formulario. Es la primera vez que lo hago. Me estoy basando en este link:  
https://desarrolloweb.com/articulos/posibilidades-envio-mail-php-localhost.html  
He instalado la herramienta test mail server para simular un servidor de mail:  
http://www.toolheap.com/test-mail-server-tool/  
Con esto lo que hago no es mandar un mail sino "falsear" un envío. Con esto quiero decir que el mail no llega realmente a destinatario, sino que llega a una carpeta de la herramienta test mail server.  
También he configurado el archivo php.ini de XAMPP para que trabaje con test mail server según:  
http://ejemplocodigo.com/ejemplo-xampp-enviar-un-email-en-localhost/

Mi código es muy sencillo:

```
<?php
$mensaje = "Esto es una prueba";

if (mail('postmaster@localhost', 'prueba envio correo', $mensaje)) {
echo "email enviado con éxito";
} else{
echo "fallo de envío";
}
?>
```

Cuando lo ejecuto aparece un mensaje de éxito, pero no llega nada a la carpeta de test mail server, entonces necesito saber si el código funciona y porqué no llega nada a la carpeta.

Comment: Lo he vuelto a hacer de nuevo y ahora funciona. Ahora sí recibo un archivo  en la carpeta de test mail server. Debe haber sido algún problema con el software o con mi conexión.

Answer (score 1):

Para el envío de correos puedes ocupar una librería que se llama [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer).
Ejemplo de código:

```
require("class.phpmailer.php");
$mail = new PHPMailer();

//Luego tenemos que iniciar la validación por SMTP:
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Host = ""; // A RELLENAR. Aquí pondremos el SMTP a utilizar. Por ej. mail.midominio.com
$mail->Username = ""; // A RELLENAR. Email de la cuenta de correo. ej.info@midominio.com La cuenta de correo debe ser creada previamente. 
$mail->Password = ""; // A RELLENAR. Aqui pondremos la contraseña de la cuenta de correo
$mail->Port = 465; // Puerto de conexión al servidor de envio. 
$mail->From = ""; // A RELLENARDesde donde enviamos (Para mostrar). Puede ser el mismo que el email creado previamente.
$mail->FromName = ""; //A RELLENAR Nombre a mostrar del remitente. 
$mail->AddAddress("correo"); // Esta es la dirección a donde enviamos 
$mail->IsHTML(true); // El correo se envía como HTML 
$mail->Subject = “Titulo”; // Este es el titulo del email. 
$body = “Hola mundo. Esta es la primer línea ”; 
$body .= “Aquí continuamos el mensaje”;
$mail->Body = $body; // Mensaje a enviar. 
$exito = $mail->Send(); // Envía el correo.

if ($exito) { 
   echo ‘El correo fue enviado correctamente.’; 
} else { 
   echo ‘Hubo un problema. Contacta a un administrador.’; 
}
```